# iOS Swift - How to detect system Alarm in app

Tags: ios, swift

How to detect system alarm in app / iOS, Swift ?

I have to react to such system event. Such alarm - set inside clock app -  will not send app into background, so no app lifecycle nor view lifecycle event is beeing called.

I also tried to add NotificationCenter but not sure about type of such notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveData(_:)), name: .didReceiveData, object: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: Not possible. You can’t access events in the Clock.app sandbox any more than Clock.app can access your notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You should expect a `didResignActiveNotification` notification when it pops up. However, this notification comes for many other reasons as well (such as an incoming phone call). There is no way to know specifically that it is Clock.app.

Answer (score 1):

In my tests the alarm doesn't trigger `didResignActiveNotification`. I'm having an issue where our video stream (WebRTC) is silencing the system alarm after about 1-2 seconds.